# Select file to delete. To delete,type file No<space>file No. example 3 1

Tags: c#, arrays

need to delete multiple files in an array can't figure out how

```
Console.WriteLine("Select file to delete To delete,type file No<space>file No. example 3 1");
string bye = Console.ReadLine();                    
foreach(FileInfo f in fiArr)
    {
        File.Delete(f.FullName);
    }
```

this code will delete all files in the array i need it to only delete selected files in the array

Comment: If `fiArr` is your array with all the files, you need to make another array with the selected files, then use that array in the foreach

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to convert the user input into an array of integers, and then for each integer they entered, delete that item from our file array using the integer index.

I've subtracted 1 from each index entered by the user, because arrays are zero-based. So if the user enters `1` to delete the first item, we want to delete the item at index `0`.

Note that since it appears you have an array of `FileInfo` objects, I'm calling the `Delete()` method on the object itself:

```
int temp = 0;

// Convert input string to an integer array by splitting on the space character and
// using int.TryParse to convert the entry to an integer.
// Also, since arrays are zero-based, we subtract 1 from the input value.
// Finally, we only select integers that are valid indexes in our file array.
int[] indexesToDelete = bye
    .Split(' ')
    .Where(item => int.TryParse(item, out temp) && temp > 0 && temp <= fiArr.Length)
    .Select(x => temp - 1)
    .ToArray(); 

// For each index, call 'Delete' on that object
foreach(int index in indexesToDelete)
{
    fiArr[index].Delete();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ` && temp >= 1 && temp <= fiArr.Length`?